# Can't open mdb file

Tags: ms-access

I have a database in mdb format that will not open.  When I try to open the file I get an error:
"The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change data at the same time"

I was the only user accessing the database and this occurred after a compact/repair.

Any ideas on how to get the db working again?

Answer (score 0):

open the .ldb file with Notepad, its name is the same as your .mdb file and its located on the same folder, you'l see info about the person 'locking' this database.

TO bypass it all, just copy the .MDB and paste it in the same folder, the lockings are not copied with it, so you can continue working on the copy of the mdb regardless.